# Very slow RegEx in AHK yet fast in Notepad++

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I'd like to find a certain string in a webpage. I decided to use RegEx. (I know my RegExes are quite terrible, however, they work). My two expressions are very fast when used in Notepad++ (probably < 1s) and on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qJ2pF8/1), but they are horribly slow when used in AutoHotKey – about 2-5 minutes. How do I fix this?

```
sWindowInfo2 = http://www.archiwum.wyborcza.pl/Archiwum/1,0,4583161,20060208LU-DLO,Dzis_bedzie_Piast,.html

whr := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
whr.Open("GET", sWindowInfo2, false ), whr.Send()
whr.ResponseText
sPage := ""
sPage := whr.ResponseText
; get city name (if exists) – the following is very slooooow
if RegExMatch(sPage, "[\s\S]+<dzial>Gazeta\s(.+)<\/dzial>[\s\S]+")
{
    sCity := RegExReplace(sPage, "[\s\S]+<dzial>Gazeta\s(.+)<\/dzial>[\s\S]+", "$1")
    ;MsgBox, % sCity
    city := 1
}
if RegExMatch(sPage, "[\s\S]+<metryczka>GW\s(.+)\snr[\s\S]+")
{
    sCity := RegExReplace(sPage, "[\s\S]+<metryczka>GW\s(.+)\snr[\s\S]+", "$1")
    city := 1
}
```

**EDIT:**
In the page I provided the match is `Lublin`. Have a look at: https://regex101.com/r/qJ2pF8/1

Comment: What exactly should the regexes match? Witout some examples we can't improve them!

Comment: Open the source of the page and run RegEx. You will get "Lublin". You can also use the link I provided.

Comment: Why don't you use `.` instead of this `[\s\S]`?

Comment: @Łukasz `.` won't catch newlines.

Comment: Why don't you use `O)<metryczka>GW\s(.+)\snr`? Then just `Match.Value(1)` will show `Lublin'. *If a capital O is present in the RegEx's options, a match object is stored in **UnquotedOutputVar**.*

Comment: And `.` will match newlines with the *DotAll* (singel line) modifier - `s).+<metryczka>GW\s(.+)\snr.+`. (The beginning `s)`.)  But as Wiktor pointed out, there shouldn't be a need to match the surrounding text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `RegExReplace` to get the captured value. As per reference, you can pass the 3rd var into [`RegExMatch`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm):

> `OutputVar`
>   `OutputVar` is the unquoted name of a variable in which to store a match object, which can be used to retrieve the position, length and value of the overall match and of **each captured subpattern, if any are present**.

So, use a much simpler pattern:

```
FoundPos := RegExMatch(sPage, "<metryczka>GW\s(.+)\snr", SubPat)  ;
```

It will return the position of the match, and will store "Lublin" in `SubPat[1]`.

With this pattern, you avoid heavy backtracking you had with `[\s\S]+<metryczka>GW\s(.+)\snr[\s\S]+` as the first `[\s\S]+` matched up to the end of the string, and then backtracked to accommodate for the subsequent subpatterns. The longer the string, the slower the operation is.

Comment: Perfect! As always. I had started to strip my string to make it shorter (it was initially ~80 kB) and you provided me with this excellent solution. I changed my initial RegEx `[\s\S]+<dzial>Gazeta\s(.+)<\/dzial>[\s\S]+` to `<dzial>Gazeta\s(.+)<\/dzial>` and it also works flawlessly!